# Is this a WPF Touch issue?

Tags: wpf, touch, multi-touch

I am having a label box and some controls in the WPF window. I am throwing a message box in the WPF Checkbox set property.

When we touch on the label message box is thrown, but even if we tough the other areas also, message box is thrown.

**This issue is occurring only in the touch monitors**

Please check the below code: [For simplicity, I have refactored for easy understanding]

**XAML**

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkbox"   Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"   Background="Red"
Content="SampleCheckBox" 
IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckBoxValue}" Margin="18,4,0,0"></CheckBox>
```

**XAML Style**

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static  SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlanchedAlmond"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
<Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
```

**Code**

```
public class GridViewModel : ViewModelBase1
{
    public bool dummyFlag = true;

    public bool testflag = false;

    public System.Windows.UIElement view;

    public bool CheckBoxValue
    {
        get { return testflag; }
        set
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("test", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            //OnPropertyChanged("CheckBoxValue");
        }
    }
}
```

**Possible Cause for the issue**

1. Throwing a message box in the set property. If I remove the message box, debugging flow doesn't go to the set property.
2. Also If I configure the below setter property to Release, issue will not occur. Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="**Release**"

however it is not the real cause of this issue.

Any help would be great.

Comment: please do the following 
1) place a brakepoint. in the setter. 
2) open the stacktrace window and copy paste it's contents into the question.